# How do I set trusted Sectigo SSL on a Actix server in RUST?

Tags: sockets, ssl, rust, actix-web

Based on my code using a `.pem` SSL certificate and key, I would like to know how I can use a Sectigo SSL that has Root CA Certificate - AAACertificateServices.crt, Intermediate CA Certificate - USERTrustRSAAAACA.crt, Intermediate CA Certificate - SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt and Your PositiveSSL Certificate - example_com.crt.

Here is my server source code portion

```
    let conf = config::get_config_file_path();
    let server_ip = conf.server_ip;
    let port =  conf.port;
    let port_ssl = conf.port_ssl;
    let cache = conf.cache;
    let ssl_dir = conf.ssl_dir;

    let server_url_ssl = format!("{}:{}",server_ip,port_ssl);
    let server_url = format!("{}:{}",server_ip,port);
    

    let mut builder =
              SslAcceptor::mozilla_intermediate(SslMethod::tls()).unwrap();
        builder
              .set_private_key_file(format!("{}{}",&ssl_dir,"/key.pem").as_str(), SslFiletype::PEM)
              .unwrap();
          builder.set_certificate_chain_file(format!("{}{}",&ssl_dir,"/cert.pem").as_str()).unwrap();
    
    HttpServer::new(|| {
        let cors_ = Cors::permissive();

        App::new()
            .wrap(cors_)
            .service(method_1)
    })
    .bind(server_url.as_str())?
    .bind_openssl(server_url_ssl.as_str(),builder)?    
    .run()
    .await
```

Thank you.